# Origin of "Bourreau de travail"

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, étymologie, histoire

According to http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/20292/bourreau-de-travail/

> Origine inconnue pour cette expression.

The question is evident. What could be some possible assertions about the origin of "bourreau de travail"?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure  ^^ but here is another question : https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/bourreau-de-travail , they used : drogué **du** boulot, isn't it drogué **au** boulot ?

Comment: @SkyLand77 Addict of work vs. Addict at work.

Comment: Oh haha thank you it's clear, it's better to be : un drogué du boulot rather than drogué au boulot

Comment: @SkyLand77 —  *Drogué du boulot* peut s'entendre : « Le travail est sa drogue », alors que *Drogué du boulot* a le même sens, son travail est une drogue, ou qu'il s'adonne à d'autres drogues sur son lieu de travail

Comment: @Personne Tu as écrit deux fois *drogué du boulot*, je suppose que la deuxième devrait être *drogué au boulot* (comme *drogué à l'héroïne*).

Comment: @jlliagre — Exact : *Drogué **du** boulot* peut s'entendre : « Le travail est sa drogue », alors que *Drogué **au** boulot* a le même sens, son travail est une drogue, *ou* qu'il s'adonne à d'autres drogues sur son lieu de travail. Il picole, sniffe,  avale des amphétamines *au* boulot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les bourreaux, chargés d'exécuter les condamnés à mort mais aussi de torturer les prisonniers soumis à la question, n'avaient, on s'en doute, pas une bonne réputation. On leur reprochait leur intransigeance, leur insensibilité et l'implacabilité avec laquelle ils effectuait le travail qui leur était demandé. C'étaient des parias de la société et ils n'avaient pas d'autre occupation.

*Bourreau de travail* désigne donc par analogie, une personne qui ne ménage pas ses efforts, que rien ni personne n'arrête dans son travail pour lequel il consacre toute son énergie.

Il est possible que l'expression provienne de l'occitan et en particulier du Sud-Ouest car on trouve dans le [Dictionnaire de la langue romano-castraise et des contrées limitrophes](https://books.google.fr/books?id=crZUnISCi3oC&dq=%22bourreau%20de%20travail%22&hl=fr&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q=%22bourreau%20de%20travail%22&f=false), 1850:

> *aco's un bourréou de trabal*: c'est un bourreau de travail

L'expression est aussi présente dans les [*Memoires Historiques de M. le Chevalier de Fonvielle, Toulouse*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WwFfAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22bourreau%20de%20travail%22&hl=fr&pg=PA478#v=onepage&q=bourreau%20de%20travail&f=false), 1824:

> *Cependant, dans toute l'administration, dès le premier mois, ma réputation d'être, ce qu'on appelle un bourreau de travail, commença à s'exprimer d'une autre manière...*

*Bourreau* a donné d'autres expressions idiomatiques où ce mot a souvent gardé le sens de *celui qui fait souffrir*, mais atténué ou au deuxième degré :

- Bourreau d'enfants
- Bourreau des cœurs : séducteur
- Bourreau d'argent, plus rare : prodigue

Comment: Intéressant, j'ai toujours cru qu'on disait cela simplement parce qu'un bourreau de travail exécute, abat ou élimine beaucoup de travail...

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, ça ne me paraît pas incompatible. Le point commun est l'excès.

Comment: Que *travail* trouve sa source dans *trepalium*, appareil de torture, matériel lié à l'endroit où le *bourreau* épanouit son art, ou soit un dispositif pour maintenir les animaux pour des soins douloureux ou encore une salle d'accouchement où surtout les primipares passent de bien pénibles moments, la souffrance dirigée habite ces deux mots. En filigrane, *le bourreau de travail* s'auto applique la souffrance du stress.

Comment: @Personne Intéressant, mais cette étymologie de travail est quand même très contestée... https://www.penserletravailautrement.fr/mf/2016/09/tripalium.html

Comment: @Personne https://web.archive.org/web/20161027102840/https://www.penserletravailautrement.fr/mf/2016/09/tripalium.html

Comment: Article intéressant, et une note d'humour indiquerait que les linguistes francophones sont de la caste de brahmanes (6 % de la population indienne) qui n'ont pas le droit de suer en travaillant dans de vils métiers …